# DB connection pooling in Neo4j jdbc driver

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

In my application I'm using neo4j-community-2.3.0-M02 with neo4j-jdbc 2.3.2 . It creates large number of threads each should execute 3 or 4 cypher queries. To execute queries I use following method,

```
    private ResultSet executeCypher(String queryString) throws Exception {
    try {
        String restUrl = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_url");
        String driver = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_driver");
        String userName = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_user");
        String passWord = getPropertiesCache().getCofigProperty("neo4j_pwd");
        Class.forName(driver);
        try{
            Neo4jConnection connection = (Neo4jConnection) 
                    DriverManager.getConnection(restUrl, userName, passWord);
            try {
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
                try{
                    ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
                    stmt.close();
                    connection.close();
                    return rs;
                }catch (SQLException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RuntimeException e2){
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(!stmt.isClosed()){
                    stmt.close();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(!connection.isClosed()){
                connection.close();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which means I'm creating db connection for each cypher query. I think it's very bad idea because when creating large number of connections most of them start to be timeout. I think db connection pooling will help on this case or is there any better idea regarding this than connection pool?

If connection pooling solve this issue, please give an example of how to create db connection pool using neo4j jdbc driver.

Comment: Can you use version 3 of the library?

Answer (score 0):

The neo4j-jdbc 2.3X driver uses the REST API to connect to the database, basically they are http calls using Restlet API, so there is no connection being opened or closed when you create/close JDBC connections.

Comment: Wouldn't it still open/close HTTP connection for every query? And if you want to limit the number of simultaneous requests? This is the very idea of connection pooling...

Comment: When using neo4j-jdbc we dont have access to http Client / Connection for pooling